# Add text in splash screen React Native Bootsplash

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, splash-screen

Splash Screen works fine, but i need to add text at the bottom and not able to achieve it, is it possible to add Text at the bottom

**PS** I am using react native bootsplash library

Answer (score -1):

You could modify the `App.tsx` file. (Maybe another name in your project).
Below are extracted from its example:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "700",
    margin: 20,
    lineHeight: 30,
    color: "#333",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  bootsplash: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
  },
  logo: {
    height: 89,
    width: 100,
  },
});
```

So to align the text to the bottom of the page, you could change the text style properties, such as:

```
text: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "700",
    lineHeight: 30,
    color: "#333",
    textAlign: "center",
    position: fixed,
    bottom: 0,
    margin-bottom: 2%,  /* Add some space before the border */
  }
```